# SQL statement to return Null values for multiple columns if no rows found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-null

I have a problem coming up with a way to solve this problem. Namely, I want the second SELECT statement to return null values even if the row is not found using the WHERE clause.

I tried many different solutions, but nothing worked (using IF, CTE, etc.). Can you please help?

```
    SELECT  RA.id
        ,AllEngagementsAndJobCodes =
        (
            SELECT 
            (
                SELECT
                (...)

                For JSON Path
            ) AS  engagements
            ,
            (
                SELECT [someColumn] as [id], [someColumn2] as [name]
                FROM [someInterface].[someSchema].[someTable]
                WHERE [someID] = '12345'

                For JSON Path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
            ) as jobCodes
        For JSON Path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
        )
```

The output of this should be one column (which is trivial for this question) and the second column containing the JSON path, which should look something like this:

```
    {
        "engagements": [
            {
                //results of the first query, not siginificant for the question
            }
        ],
        "jobCodes": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

Note that if the query DOES return something, it might be more than one row and all of them need to be included in the output JSON.

Comment: You should probably provide a working query, sample data, current and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: I'll use a LEFT JOIN with the same table, with no conditions on the LEFT component and COALESCE for the right elements. If you provide a working sample, I can try to rewrite the query this way.

Comment: Well this is a working sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using a common table expression and `union all`:

```
;WITH CTEInnerQuery AS
(
    SELECT [someColumn] as [id], [someColumn2] as [name]
    FROM [someInterface].[someSchema].[someTable]
    WHERE [someID] = '12345'
), CTEInnerJson AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTEInnerQuery
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL as [id], NULL as [name]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTEInnerQuery)
)

SELECT  RA.id
    ,AllEngagementsAndJobCodes =
    (
        SELECT 
        (
            SELECT
            (...)

            For JSON Path
        ) AS  engagements
        ,
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM CTEInnerJson
            For JSON Path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        ) as jobCodes
    For JSON Path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )
```

Comment: When I try to run this, I get the error: `The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.` and when I wrap the inner query in another SELECT, I get this error: `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. Please try the updated code.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, I spent 2 days trying to figure this out..

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick the resolve your problem

```
IF(NOT EXISTS (...))
BEGIN
    SELECT  0 AS UserID
            ,N'' UserName
    WHERE 1 = 2

    RETURN;
END
```